# Escapar el signo / en consulta postgresql desde php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy realizando un consulta a BD Postgresql desde PHP, lo que intento obtener es a demas de todos lo campo es dividr el campo **antiguedad_mes entre 12** (script)

```
$consulta  = "SELECT numemp, TO_CHAR(fecha,'DD-tmMonth-YYYY')AS fecha, centro, puesto,**round(antiguedad_mes/12,2)** ";
$consulta .= " FROM epcpplemp WHERE numemp=$empleadoExpCpl ORDER BY date_part('year',fecha) desc ";
```

de la manera que lo tengo actualmente en mi codigo php me marca error de sintaxis al escribir el signo de dividir, ya intente escapar con barra invertidad \ y con con comillas simples y dobles pero no logro dar con el resultado, los errores que me muestra son error de sintaxis en php y error del plugin datatable que uso y por que no recibe el dato correcto

DataTables warning: table id=tablaExpCppl - Requested unknown parameter 'antiguedad_mes' for row 0, column 4. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Si me pueden ayudar porfavor

Comment: Hola! Por favor, procura incluir los mensajes de error completos en tu pregunta. Siempre puedes [edit] y mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: encontre mi propio error jaja, muchas gracias, no se ocupa escapar el caracter / (dividir ) solo agregarle un alias en la consulta... gracias

Comment: Por favor, ponlo como respuesta abajo en el campo Tu Respuesta junto con la solución que encontraste! Recuerda que la idea es ayudar a otros con el mismo problema en el futuro. Puedes incluso marcarlo como aceptado en unas horas y recibirás votos positivos! :)